Adjusting thickness in itembox
I have recently read this very nice solution to a question about diagrams. The answer was as follows:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$C$}
  \begin{minipage}[c][.6\linewidth]{\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& a \arrow[rd,"g"] \&  \\
            b \arrow[ru, "f"] \arrow[rr,"g\circ f"] \&  \& c \\
        \end{tikzcd}
     \end{minipage}     
\end{itembox}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\linewidth}
    \centering
    $\overset{F}{\longrightarrow}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
\begin{itembox}[l]{$D$}
   \begin{minipage}[c][.6\linewidth]{\linewidth}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
             \& F(a) \arrow[rd,"F(g)"] \&  \\
            F(b) \arrow[ru, "F(f)"] \arrow[rr,"F(g\circ f)"] \&  \& F(c) \\
        \end{tikzcd}
     \end{minipage}
\end{itembox}%
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


I was wondering: is there a way to locally adjust the line thickness of each itembox?

not as far as I can tell. I don't read japanese and I don't fully understand the code (which I admit I didn't read from the beginning) but, as far as I can determine, the package hard-codes the line widths at 0.8pt. you could fairly easily implement something similar which would be more flexible, if you wanted. or you could just use e.g. tcolorbox or simply tikz, since you have the overhead of loading that already.

alternatively, you could try contacting the package's author to make a feature request. or you could just add a frame to the tikzpicture you're creating for each diagram.

As far as I can tell, the line width is hardwired into the code and cannot be adjusted either locally or globally. However, I don't read Japanese and didn't fully follow the admittedly isolated fragment of code I looked at. So I do not want to say there is no way, but only that I could not easily identify one.
But it would be easy to implement something similar with more flexibility in terms of customisation. pgf/tikz might be overkill just for the boxes, but you're already using it for the diagram, so why not just add a frame to the tikzpicture? You do not even need a separate environment. Then you can adjust the box locally or globally using the full range of features provided by pgf/tikz.
The following provides a style item box with configurable height, depth, frame thickness, frame colour, rounded corners and label distance from corner. The example demonstrates how to change the values of these options locally and how to set them globally. It also shows how to apply additional options such as a background fill.
The resulting image looks rather odd because I've shown a box using the initial options on the left and one using modified settings on the right, which probably isn't what you'd actually want to typeset in a real document but hopefully does duty for illustrative purposes.
I'm not sure the interface is quite right - I am bad at designing using interfaces using pgfkeys, but hopefully you will get the general idea.
This method also cuts down on the number of minipages required for alignment because we can use tikz to align things and set the appropriate dimensions.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/726987/
  /item box/.cd,
  line width/.initial=0.8pt,
  frame colour/.initial=black,
  corners/.initial=10pt,
  label shift/.initial=12pt,
  box ht/.initial=1.5cm,
  box dp/.initial=1.5cm,
  frame/.style={},
  /tikz/.cd,
  /item box/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  item box/.style={%
    /tikz/.cd,
    execute at end picture={%
      \scoped[on background layer] {%
        \node [draw,inner sep=0pt,text height=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/box ht},text depth=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/box dp},minimum width=\linewidth-\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/line width},line width=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/line width},draw=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/frame colour},rounded corners=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/corners},/item box/.cd,frame] at (current bounding box.center) {};
      }
      \node [anchor=west,fill=white,xshift=\pgfkeysvalueof{/item box/label shift} ] at (current bounding box.north west) {$#1$};
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,/tikz/item box=C]
    \& a \arrow[rd,"g"] \&  \\
    b \arrow[ru, "f"] \arrow[rr,"g\circ f"] \&  \& c \\
  \end{tikzcd}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\linewidth}
  \centering
  $\overset{F}{\longrightarrow}$
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&,/tikz/item box=D,/item box/frame/.style={line width=1.5pt,frame colour=black!75!gray,corners=15pt,label shift=15pt,top color=white,bottom color=gray!50,fill opacity=.2}]
    \& F(a) \arrow[rd,"F(g)"] \&  \\
    F(b) \arrow[ru, "F(f)"] \arrow[rr,"F(g\circ f)"] \&  \& F(c) \\
  \end{tikzcd}%
\end{minipage}
\end{document}


In fact, I think you could probably eliminate all but one minipage here and very possibly all of them.
